# jQuery does not trigger events using .trigger (except click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I have several Input-Fields whose values are displayed in my DOM tree. When I type something in the DOM-tree updates, but when I update the input-Field via `.val()` and then trigger the event with `.trigger("input")` nothing happens.

My input-field looks like this:

```
<input value="This is a loaded text!" id="navInput4-0" data-iid="4-0" class="navInput form-control" type="text" />
```

The Event handler is bind through

```
$("#side-menu-div input[type!='file'], #side-menu-div textarea").unbind("input").on("input", function(){...});
```

And I try to trigger the event through

```
$("#navInput"+index+"-0").val(val).trigger("input");
```

The variable index is filled with a valid number -> .val(val) works fine!
I also tried to seperate the parts with no effect...

```
$("#navInput"+index+"-0").val(val);
$("#navInput"+index+"-0").trigger("input");
```

I also tried to trigger the event using

```
$("#side-menu-div input[type!='file'], #side-menu-div textarea").trigger("input");
$("*").trigger("input");
```

but nothing happened....

I also tried to bind the change-Event too, as this is what solved all the problems i found, and call it with `.change()` but this also won't work...

```
$("#side-menu-div input[type!='file'], #side-menu-div textarea").unbind("input change").on("input change", function(){...});
$("#navInput"+index+"-0").val(val).change();
```

Is this kind of a bug in jQuery 2.2.4 or am I missing an obvious part?

Comment: you could try `keyup`

Comment: @a-rossi It is a event which fires everytime value changes. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: Why `input` is not an event? @A.Rossi

Comment: Yeah, nevermind, never saw it before, i already used "change" event. i'll remove my coment

Comment: Hi, did you check that your selector `$("#navInput"+index+"-0")` working? (check it with the `length` property)

Comment: I just tried something with `trigger(input)` looks work. https://jsfiddle.net/syjtqp30/2/